# Why sorting by price not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dom, ecmascript-6

In the `sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder)` method, sorting does not work when I delete or add new products, sorting works only for products that are in the `this.products` array by default.

**(Products are sorted by clicking `<th> Price: </ th>`).**

It is necessary that sorting can use too  after removal / addition of goods.

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    //method for remove product by name
    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // get total price by all products
    get totalProductsPrice() {
        return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    }

    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
        const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
        });
        this.products = sorted;
    }

    // method to draw the table with product property (
    // name, count, price)
show() {
    const formAdd = document.forms[0];
    const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
    const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
    const formDelete = document.forms[1];
    const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
    const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
    const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");
    // add new product by click
    buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
            parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
shop.show();
    }, false);
    // delete product by name after click
    buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
shop.show();
    }, false);
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
    for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const e = rows.item(i);
        e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    }
    const table = document.getElementById("shop");
    const tFoot = table.querySelector('tfoot');
    if (tFoot) tFoot.remove();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        //create table
        table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
<td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
<td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
    }
    //show total price by all products
    table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3" id="total-price">Total price: 
    ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;

    priceFilter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
shop.show();
    }, false);
}
}

let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 2, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 3, 1000));
shop.show();
 
console.log(shop.products);
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
    <div class="add-product">
        <h1>Add product</h1>
        <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<div class="product-table">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <form id="delete-form">
        <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
        <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PeterB yes, on click

Comment: try this `console.log(shop.sortProductsByPrice(-1))` because your function is working properly.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav add a new product. Sorting fails

Comment: The answer below is correct, you need to update this.products after sorting. There are also some improvements which can be made to your sort function and to your deleteByName function. I'd use a filter to delete and for sorting just `(a.price - b.price)*order` where order is either `1` or `-1`

Comment: After clicking it filters but then there is nothing to toggle the direction so it just applies the same filter again. I would use a data attribute on the filter to tell it which direction to filter, and when you filter update that attribute to be the opposite.

Comment: if you add a console.log to the click handler on the #filter element, you can see that it only runs the first time it's clicked; the handler's getting unbound somewhere in there.

Comment: Might be getting removed when the table re-renders then.

Comment: Just FYI this is what React.js would be good for :)

Comment: @IgorShvets That's another problem, because you are not attaching the events in the `show()` method, they are only atatched in the first place, and in your `show()` method you are redrawing the whole HTML without events binding. Thta's why they don't work after Addition/removal, because you call the `show()` method there.

Comment: @chŝdk Do not tell me how to make this binding to events?

Comment: @IgorShvets Just move the `addeventListner` codes to the `show()`method, just a little arrangement.

Comment: @chŝdk that is, remove the "show ()" method from the handlers and add all handlers to the "show ()" method, did this and now the code does not work, please help to understand (see the edited code above)

Comment: @IgorShvets No you don't need to remove `show()` call from the event handlers, you just need to attach them inside of it.

Comment: @chŝdk Did everything as you said, all the handlers work except sorting by the price, help to understand why (see the edited code above)

Comment: @IgorShvets The problem is that you are declaring `priceFilter` as constant, so it's value won't change after reassigning the HTML, and thus it will point to old element, you need to place the line `const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");`, just after the code where you reassign the HTML, in other words the line before the filter event binding.

Comment: @chŝdk No, my problem did not decided, and appeared a new, when I add a product, then the quantity that has already been added and + 1 is added. This can be seen with the second addition

Comment: The problem is that you are mixing both codes that construct the HTML and bind the events, what should be better is to separate the code that updates only the tables rows, without the heade and keep the code that initialises the header of the table with the one that binds event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is necessary that sorting can use too after removal / addition of goods

The sorting is not working after addition/removal because you are calling `show()` method after adding/removing element, which will redraw the whole HTML, without attaching any events to it, so the originally attached event handlers will be unbound.

You need to attach the event handlers in your `show()` method to resolve this problem.

---

And there's no need to return the sorted array in your method, the original `this.products` will be sorted in place.

So there's no need to declare `sorted` array, and return it, just write the `this.products.sort()` code it will sort the array.

```
 sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
    this.products.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
    });
 }
```

**Demo:**

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
  constructor(name, count, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
  constructor() {
    this.products = [];
  }

  //method for adding a product
  addProduct(newProduct) {
    this.products.push(newProduct);
  }

  //method for remove product by name
  deleteProductByName(productName) {
    let i = this.products.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
        this.products.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  // get total price by all products
  get totalProductsPrice() {
    return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
  }

  //method for sorting the product at its price
  sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
    this.products.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
    });
  }

  // method to draw the table with product property (
  // name, count, price)
  show() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
    for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const e = rows.item(i);
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    }
    const table = document.getElementById("shop");
    const tFoot = table.querySelector('tfoot');
    if (tFoot) tFoot.remove();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      //create table
      table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
    }
    //show total price by all products
    table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3" id="total-price">Total price: 
        ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;
  }
}
// add new product by click
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
    parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
  shop.show();
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
  shop.show();
}, false);
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 2, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 3, 1000));
shop.show();
const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");
//filter products by price
priceFilter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
  shop.show();
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
  <div class="add-product">
    <h1>Add product</h1>
    <form id="addForm">
      <label for="name">Name of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="input-product">
      <label for="price">Price of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="price" class="input-product">
      <label for="count">Count of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="count" class="input-product">
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="product-table">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <form id="delete-form">
      <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
      <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <table id="shop">
      <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th id="filter">Price:</th>
        <th>Count:</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I replaced the return "sorted" with "this.products = sorted" but after the addition or removal of the product, the sorting does not work when clicking on "<th>Price:</th>"

Comment: @IgorShvets Thatt's another problem, Ibecause you are not attaching the events in the `show()` method, they are only atatched in the first place, and in your `show()` method you are redrawing the whole HTML without events binding.

Comment: The event handler on #filter is getting unbound somehow after the first click (I haven't traced how yet); the original code did sort successfully on the first try, exactly as in this answer.

Comment: @DanielBeck That's because he is calling `show()` method which will redraw the HTML without events handlers, he should attach the events in `show()` method.